# DPM Self Service Recovery Tool (SQL) installation failure

Tags: scdpm

I'm trying to install the Microsoft System Center 2022 DPM Self Service Recovery tool intended to allow SQL Server DBAs to do their own recoveries (described and linked to at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/dpm/back-up-sql-server?view=sc-dpm-2022#allow-sql-server-admins-to-restore-data).  The installer has an .msi extension. On Windows 11 when I first ran it (right-click and Install from Explorer) I got a message to install NET framework 3.5 SP1; so I did that using the Windows tool to install features (according to registry entries Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5 and Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5\SP it is in fact installed).  Now when I run it, after clicking the Install button in the dialog, I get a pop-up "Launch setup.exe for installing." I've tried using the Powershell cmdlet unblock-file in case it's a problem with MotW but that hasn't solved it.

Ideas?  Does this work for others?

thanks!

Martin

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is an acknowledged (by MS Support) problem in the packaging of this tool.  It can be installed using msiexec, like this (in cmd window, from directory containing the .msi):

```
msiexec.exe /i DPMSQLEur_x64.msi bootstrapped=1
```

Martin